# Csharp: Generar un nuevo vector tipo texto,que almacene la conversión a binario de un vector de tipo entero

Tags: c#, array

hola alguien sabe por que no funciona ?
el ejercicio pide que se almacene en un vector tipo texto la conversión de un vector tipo entero

```
static void Vectortexto(ref int[] b,ref int n)
        {
            String[] a;
            a = new string[n];
            for (int i= 0; i> b.Length; i ++)
            {
              while(b[i]%2!=0 || b[i]%2 != 1)
                {
                    b[i] = b[i] / 2;
                    if (b[i] % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        a[i] = "0";
                        Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
                        if (b[i] % 2 == 1)
                        {
                            a[i] = "1";
                            Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i= 0; i> b.Length; i ++)
```

Este bucle for no arrancará, por la condición i > b.Length, debería ser i < b.Length

La variable n, cumple la misma función que b.Length???

```
while(b[i]%2!=0 || b[i]%2 != 1)
```

Cuando divides entre dos, el módulo es 1 o 0, es decir, el número siempre es par o es impar. Tu condición while, se lee: Mientras no sea par o no sea impar, es siempre VERDADERO, es lo mismo que while(1).. y sería un bucle infinito si la ejecución llegara a ese punto.

La forma más práctica y simple de convertir a binario en C# es

```
a[i] = Convert.ToString(b[i], 2)
```

De todos modos:

```
if (b[i] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    a[i] = "0";
                    Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
                    if (b[i] % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        a[i] = "1";
                        Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
                    }
```

El if anidado, no se ejecutará nunca, ya que es contrario al if superior y el valor de b[i] no cambia en ese ámbito.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda